# urlib3 https Not connected

Tags: python, urllib3

I have local ubuntu server.
I try in local ubuntu server

```
import certifi
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
    ca_certs=certifi.where())
http.request('GET', 'https://dormi.kongju.ac.kr/main/contents/food.php?mid=40&k=2')
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7fab2c8c40f0>
r = http.request('GET', 'https://dormi.kongju.ac.kr/main/contents/food.php?mid=40&k=2')
print(r.data)
```

[image]

It's well-connected.

but not connect in digitalocean

I need help

Comment: Before you crawl the target website, please make sure your target which you can reach by use `ping dormi.kongju.ac.kr`.

Comment: I can't ping my fingers strangely.
What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe the target server is die~

Comment: But you can access the homepage!